# How can I resubmit data to a SocketConnect object without creating a new socket?

Tags: socket

I have a Python function that can be accessed over a TCP connection on port `1234`. In Wolfram Language, I have the following code:

```
ClearAll[getResFromPython];
getResFromPython[sock_][arg_String] := (
    WriteString[sock, ExportString[<|"arg" -> arg|>, "JSON"]];
    ReadString[sock]
);
```

Since the creation of a new socket is not exactly instantaneous--it takes nearly two seconds on my computer--I would like to do the following:

```
ClearAll[sock, vals];
sock = SocketConnect[{"localhost", 1234}, "TCP"];
vals = Map[getResFromPython[sock], {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"}];
Close[sock];
(* Now do something with vals. *)
```

This does not work. Only `"arg1"` is evaluated correctly, and I think it is because the socket needs to be flushed before the next argument is written to it. But I cannot find any function in the documentation that would flush the socket. There is a `WSFlush` function, but it is for an entirely different purpose.

What is the correct way to reuse a socket connection over a list of arguments?

**Edit**

In case anyone is interested, here is my simple Python setup:

```
# tcpserver.py
import socketserver
import urllib.parse
import json

def getVal(arg):
    return 1

class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = json.loads(self.request.recv(2048).strip())
        res = getVal(self.data["arg"])
        self.request.sendall(bytes(json.dumps({"res": res}), "utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 1234
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), SASTCPHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use session=StartExternalSession["Python"] for all of this instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been grappling with this for a while and finally I realized the problem is not Mathematica. `TCPHandler` appears to kill the connection after the first `handle()`. It does not **keep-alive** a connection. You could either read on and use the code at the end of my answer, or you could try connecting once and writing once in batch. This means you write all the data together for one connection by using the sequence form of `WriteString[sock, string1, string2, ..., stringn]`.

---

If you use this basic server implementation below you'll see that Mathematica is quite capable of multiple `WriteString`'s on the same socket and a single connection:

```python
import socket
from time import sleep

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 1234
BUFFER_SIZE = 2048

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

connection, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    try:
        connection.send("keeping alive".encode())
        data = connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if data:
            print("received data:" + str(data))
            connection.send("got it!".encode())
        else:
            sleep(0.06)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        connection.close()
    except socket.error:
        print("client disconnected")
        connection.close()
        break
```

... and from Mathematica:

```
sock = SocketConnect[{"localhost", 1234}, "TCP"];
WriteString[sock, "Hey!"]
Print@ByteArrayToString@SocketReadMessage[sock]
WriteString[sock, "What's up?"]
Print@ByteArrayToString@SocketReadMessage[sock]
Close[sock]
```

You should see the result server-side:

```
received data:b'Hey!'
received data:b"What's up?"
client disconnected
```

So we know it's possible. Let's look at a *Wireshark* packet dump for your `TCPServer` to see what's wrong. I monitored the loopback interface instead of Ethernet or Wi-Fi to produce the trace.

It looks like the *server* is the one terminating the connection. The server sends a `FIN` packet just before Mathematica is about to send the second item. Mathematica wasn't expecting it and it continues to send the second item *(the final [PSH, ACK] in the trace)*. Mathematica doesn't end the connection and comply with the `FIN` so the server sends a `RST` and kills the connection hard, never handling the remaining requests. After `TCPHandler.handle()` returns from processing the first item, the `TCPServer` doesn't keep the connection going.

[image: wireshark tcp packets]

If you want to keep the connection alive during the `handle()` you'll have to create a loop and a poll delay like this:

```python
# tcpserver.py
import socketserver
import urllib.parse
import json
from time import sleep

def getVal(arg):
    return 1

class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        alive = True
        while(alive):
            try:
                self.data = self.request.recv(2048)
                if self.data:
                    jsonresult = json.loads(self.data.strip())
                    res = getVal(jsonresult["arg"])
                    print(jsonresult)
                    self.request.sendall(bytes(json.dumps({"res": res}), "utf-8"))
                else:
                    print("no data")
                    time.sleep(0.06) # 60ms delay
                    continue
            except:
                print("finished!")
                alive = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 1234
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPHandler) as server:
        server.socket.settimeout(None)
        server.serve_forever()
```

... and use the following slight modification to your Mathematica code *(I've used `SocketReadMessage` instead of `ReadString`)*:

```
ClearAll[getResFromPython];
getResFromPython[sock_][arg_String] := (
   WriteString[sock, ExportString[<|"arg" -> arg|>, "JSON"]];
   ByteArrayToString@SocketReadMessage[sock]);

ClearAll[sock, vals];
sock = SocketConnect[{"localhost", 1234}, "TCP"];
vals = Map[getResFromPython[sock], {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"}];
Close[sock];
```

Finally it works!

```
{'arg': 'arg1'}
{'arg': 'arg2'}
{'arg': 'arg3'}
no data
finished!
```

It also works with sending multiple requests with delay in between which you can do like this:

```
sock = SocketConnect[{"localhost", 1234}, "TCP"];
vals = Reap[Do[
     Sow[Map[getResFromPython[sock], {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"}]];
     Pause[1];
     , 5]] // Last // First
Close[sock];
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! Thank you for that detailed and painstaking response!

Comment: Another quick question. When I try to evaluate two Maps, the second one never gets evaluated. `vals1 = Map[getResFromPython[sock], {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"}]; vals2 = Map[getResFromPython[sock], {"arg11", "arg12", "arg13"}];` The first one gives me the correct results, but the second one never seems to reach the server,

Comment: @Shredderroy Strange - maybe there is still a race of some kind. It works for me if I do `sock = SocketConnect[...]` followed by many maps followed by `Close[sock];` I even tried with a `Do` loop instead of a single Map: `vals = Reap[Do[Sow[Map[getResFromPython[sock], {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"}]],10]][[-1, 1]]` and this produces 30 results in python and 10 lists of `{"{\"res\": 1}", "{\"res\": 1}", "{\"res\": 1}"}` in mathematica. Are you sure you cleared out all old definitions and copied the above code correctly for both server and Mathematica ?

Comment: Thanks so much again. You know what made the difference? I was using `time.sleep(0.05).` Then I changed it to `time.sleep(0.06)`, and now all the various maps get evaluated correctly.

Comment: @Shredderroy Ah, in that case there's still something wrong with my code then, because  the time delay is arbitrary. If recv gets no data in the time frame then it raises an exception and this finishes off the connection. Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745561 . I'll see if I can modify the server code to fix this for arbitrary timeout. It also looks like serve_forever timeout anyway https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830693 so if you don't handle the whole request quickly enough and your second Map is issued too late,  the connection breaks down.

Comment: @Shredderroy I've removed the timeout completely - it should stay up indefinitely until the connection is closed even with considerable delay in between sending.

Comment: Thank you so much again! Yes, I was testing it by using `Pause[60 * 15]` in WL, and ensuring that when the programme resumed, the TCP server still returned the results. I need a long-running server, which I intend to call over the course of the generations of my evolutionary algorithm. The complete programme takes over eight hours to run, so I definitely need the server to accept requests after considerable delays.