# WriteString to TCP socket appears to be broken in Mathematica 12.3

Tags: python, networking, socket, version-12.3

I have a large codebase in which some functions make calls to Python TCP servers. The code used to work perfectly in `Mathematica 12.2`, but has not worked since I updated to `Mathematica 12.3` last night.

I have managed to isolate the problem to the call to `WriteString`. The following is a minimum illustration of the issue. Here is the Python server:

```py
import socketserver
import json
import time


class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        bufSz = 2048
        while True:
            self.data = self.request.recv(bufSz)
            if self.data:
                jsonReq = json.loads(self.data.strip())
                print(f"Request: {jsonReq}")
                jsonRes = json.dumps({"res": len(jsonReq["arg"])})
                print(f"Response: {jsonRes}")
                self.request.sendall(bytes(jsonRes, "utf-8"))
            else:
                time.sleep(0.10)
                self.data = ""
                continue


def main():
    host, port = "localhost", 9990
    with socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), TCPHandler) as server:
        print(f"Test server now running at {host} on port {port}")
        server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is the `Wolfram Language` code that calls it:

```
ClearAll[sock];
sock = SocketConnect[{"localhost", 9990}, "TCP"];

ClearAll[params];
params = ExportString[<|"arg" -> "test string"|>, "JSON"];

Module[{res},
    WriteString[sock, params];
    res = ByteArrayToString@SocketReadMessage[sock];
    ImportString[res, "JSON"]
]
```

This exact set-up used to work for me reliably until `Mathematica 12.2`. But now the execution hangs at the `WriteString` command.

I have tried turning off Windows firewall entirely. The problem persists.

Any assistance would be gratefully acknowledged.

Comment: Strange. It doesn't seem as though any of the functions involved have been updated in 12.3, so I'm not sure why this wouldn't be working, but it doesn't seem like it is.

Comment: I got a good connection in the end in 12.3, but still hangs.

Comment: It does seem to work fine talking to a HTTP server: `sock = SocketConnect[{"www.airfields-freeman.com", 80}, "TCP"]; WriteString[sock, "GET / HTTP/1.1 \n\n"]; ReadString[sock]` more or less works (in that I get a HTTP response from a server)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, @CarlLange and @flinty. I hope someone at `Wolfram Research` will at least provide a workaround soon. This represents a huge problem for me.

Comment: @Shredderroy this is a guess don't have 12.3 installed yet. Could it be a BOM?

Comment: @Shredderroy try `lparams = Normal[StringToByteArray[params, "UTF-8"]];
lparams = If[Take[lparams, 3] == {231, 187, 191}, Drop[lparams, 3], lparams];
params = ByteArrayToString[ByteArray[lparams], "UTF-8"];` If there is a BOM it will remove it, otherwise leave it alone. I tried your sample code in 12.2 added BOM and it failed, remove BOM and it returns a value.

Comment: @Hans thank you very much for the suggestions. I tried it out by ensuring that the BOM was not present at the head of the string. (The byte array showed that it was not anyway.) But the call to `WriteString[sock, jsonStringAfterBOMRemoval]` still hung. Then I tried adding in the BOM. The result was the same.

Comment: @Shredderroy Thanks for trying. I will give it a try at solution after I install 12.3. I usually wait a while before upgrade. But meanwhile, I hope it is not as simple as adding `\n\n` to the end of the string. This was an issues in a previous version where hint to a fix was simply adding a `\n`

Comment: Thanks so much for following up, Hans. Following your suggestion, I even tried adding `\n\n` to the string. I noticed it in the sample request in Carl Lange's comment as it. Unfortunately, the call still hangs.

Comment: Actually I think not WriteString is broken but SocketConnect. In 12.3.0 SocketReadyQ[sock] evaluates to False, while in 12.2.0 it evaluates to True

Comment: It looks like there has been a major rewrite of the ZeroMQLink in 12.3.0. Since this is a Paclet WRI might be able to fix it by a PacletUpdate.

Comment: As a workaround you can copy the ZeroMQLink Paclet from 12.2.0 (/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/ZeroMQLink) to $UserBaseDirectory/Paclets/Repository (eg. /Users/Philipp/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository)  and increase the version number in PacletInfo.m to 1.3.0. This worked for a test on my machine. Note: after a fix has been provided this paclet has to be deleted.

Comment: @Philipp thanks a lot for the suggested workaround. Is the old paclet available online? I don't have `Mathematica 12.2` on my computer anymore. I uninstalled it while installing the latest version--something I will never do in the future.

Comment: @Shredderoy: I am not sure, but you could try function PacletFindRemote for ZeroMQLink and check if it is available on the Wolfram Servers and then install it from there. You need a version < 1.2.0. After that don‘t forget to increase the version number in PacletInfo.m for the  downloaded paclet.

Comment: @Philipp `SocketReadyQ`  being `False` isn't a big deal though because it just checks if data is available to read on the socket. If you connect to a webserver you wouldn't expect it to go true until after you made a request and it replied with data.

Comment: @flinty Thank you for the info. I noticed the difference between 12.2 and 12.3 for SocketReadyQ. In 12.2 it is returning True, so I still wonder if there is an underlying issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your python TCP server implementation.

If you check the corresponding documentation, especially the example [section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#examples), you may witness that the provided TCP client code does not always work either with your server.

`client.py`:

```python
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9990
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(bytes(data + "\n", "utf-8"))

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")

print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
print("Received: {}".format(received))
```

run it with `$ python3 client.py hello!`. It sometimes hang on my machine (MacOS, Python 3.9.4).

Now if you replace your python server with the [example implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example), it's possible to interact from the Wolfram Language.

This leads me to conclude that there must be a problem with your code sample. Could you double check this first, then we can investigate further what your project issue is. Let me provide few comments about the Python server to help debugging. First of all, why do you wrap the `handler` logic inside a while? I don't think it's necessary since the `self.request.recv` is a non busy wait. It may prevent correct connection handling. Also, why would you sleep if no data was received? Maybe that makes sense in your project, in which case disregard this comment, but in the example it seems unnecessary and confusing.

When I drop the while loop, and wrap the code inside a try / except, I'm able to communicate with a Wolfram Kernel. Here is a sample python server in case it helps:

```python
import socketserver
import json
import time


class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        bufSz = 2048
        try:
            print("Waiting for a request...")
            self.data = self.request.recv(bufSz)
            print("Request received!")
            if self.data:
                jsonReq = json.loads(self.data.strip())
                print(f"Request: {jsonReq}")
                jsonRes = json.dumps({"res": len(jsonReq["arg"])})
                print(f"Response: {jsonRes}")
                self.request.sendall(bytes(jsonRes, "utf-8"))
            else:
                print("Empty request, sleeping.")
                time.sleep(0.10)
                self.data = ""
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: ", e)

def main():
    host, port = "localhost", 9990
    with socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), TCPHandler) as server:
        print(f"Test server now running at {host} on port {port}")
        server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hopefully that will help you fixing your issue.

Comment: If you drop the loop, then the connection isn't kept alive and the socket isn't re-used which is why OP is using this code. I came up with the code originally in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228575/how-can-i-resubmit-data-to-a-socketconnect-object-without-creating-a-new-socket) . There could well be a problem with it, I'm not an expert in networking, but it worked sufficiently well for OP since then.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I will try them when I get back this evening. But @flinty has already answered one of your questions. Without the while loop, the connection isn't kept alive, which means that all of the socket-related initialisation (such as loading of trained models, etc.) has to be done each time. That approach is not feasible. This code has worked without error until now.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean @flinty. It's possible to use the Python server code I've provided and run this function from the other answer multiple time: `getResFromPython[sock_][arg_String]:=(WriteString[sock,ExportString[<|"arg"->arg|>,"JSON"]];
ByteArrayToString@SocketReadMessage[sock]);`
Map the function: `vals = Map[getResFromPython[sock], {"arg1", "arg10", "arg100"}]`.
It'll return `{"{\"res\": 4}", "{\"res\": 5}", "{\"res\": 6}"}`. (tested with ZMQ Paclet version `1.2.1`)

Comment: @DorianB. that looks like it's fixed then, because prior to this in the other answer the connection would close after an unspecified timeout and you couldn't do a `WriteString` twice without a lockup, i.e there was no way to keep alive the connection because python would send a FIN, mathematica would ignore it, and then python would send a RST killing it and preventing further WriteStrings.

Comment: @DorianB. sorry, I was really preoccupied with a presentation I had to make yesterday, so I could not revisit this problem until this morning. But I can now confirm that removing the while loop from the TCP handler has corrected the problem, and my code is running once again. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: No problem at all. I glad your problem was fixed!