# obabel_mod.exe not found

Tags: chemistry, version-12.3

I don't know if this question has any connection to [this question about TCP sockets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246444/writestring-to-tcp-socket-appears-to-be-broken-in-mathematica-12-3). I encountered the problem after I was able to run my code base again following the resolution to that question.

My large code base usually takes many hours to run. It ran without error in previous versions of Mathematica. But in version 12.3, occasionally the following error message is displayed:

> RunProcess::pnfd: Program C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.3\SystemFiles\Components\Chemistry\Resources\OpenBabelLink\Windows-x86-64\obabel_mod.exe not found.  Check Environment["PATH"].

This happens at random points in the overall execution.

Did Wolfram Research forget to package a required file with the build of version 12.3?

Comment: I highly recommend you contact customer service so this can be solved.  There is not enough information here to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JasonB. thanks. I will contact them as you suggest.

Comment: I also want to add that the file is present on my computer at the location mentioned above.

Comment: do you get an output from this?  ```Chemistry`OpenBabelLink`CallOpenBabel["-:C1=CC=CC=C1", "-ismi", "-osmi"] ```

Comment: I get the following output: `<|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "c1ccccc1", "StandardError" -> "1 molecule converted"|>`

Comment: @JasonB. I want to add that when I type that into `Mathematica 12.3`, I get the output above. But when I type it into the latest version of `Wolfram Engine for Developers` through a Jupyter notebook, I don't get that result. I just get the command back in the output cell.

Comment: Okay, never mind. When I first do `Needs["Chemistry"]` in Jupyter, I get the same output as above.

Comment: That makes sense, the `CallOpenBabel` function is not a paclet autoloading symbol, so it only works after the package is read in. The output you pasted is the correct output, so as you say the executable is there. But somehow you've ended up in a state where it isn't available. Try to come up with a reproducible example if you can.  Continuing this in a chat room might be productive. Also, we need chemistry users for the pre-release program.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124925/discussion-between-shredderroy-and-jason-b).